# Im making a discord bot and i got an error (python)

Tags: python, error-handling, discord.py

im going off a website (https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/#how-to-make-a-discord-bot-in-python)
and im following there steps but i keep getting an error msg

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Bryce.Persello346\Desktop\bot.py", line 15, in 
> client.run(TOKEN)
> File "C:\Users\Bryce.Persello346\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 718, in run
> return future.result()
> File "C:\Users\Bryce.Persello346\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 697, in runner
> await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\Bryce.Persello346\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 660, in start
> await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
> File "C:\Users\Bryce.Persello346\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 509, in login
> await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

my code:

```py
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('"token here"')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59888388/receiving-a-runtime-error-at-client-runtoken-when-running-my-discord-py-bot) might help.

Comment: Make sure: a. The token is stored in an environment variable. b. the name of environment variable is the argument to `os.getenv()`. Alternatively and less secure you can add the token directly without `os.getenv()`.

Comment: Try replacing `os.getenv('"token here"')` with your token (Ex: `TOKEN = 'QWERTYUIOP...'`) to test if it's working, if it does, then you're not getting your key correctly from the **.env** file.

Comment: i did not put my token in the code for security before i published i swapped it out

Answer (score 1):

In the example on real python you may have made the mistake of putting the key in curly braces. so basically just format your env file like this...

```
DISCORD_TOKEN = token_goes_here
```

instead of...

```
DISCORD_TOKEN = {token_goes_here}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the way the token is stored

As the error says , discord.py is unable to use the token because it is not stored correctly

If you are running the code on your own local system , try not using environment variables

```
import os
import discord
TOKEN = "ABC.123.XYZ"
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

If you are running the code on online ide's (replit or others) , then do

```
import os
import discord
TOKEN = os.environ["token"]
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Hope this helps :)